# How do I display 4 columns in the product carousal instead of the current 5 columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to figure out what code to edit in order to display 4 columns instead of the current 5 for the products towards the bottom of this page: https://zadroinc.com/this-is-a-test

It's built on bigcommerce, so I may not have access to all the jquery/javascript files, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction or maybe I could insert a script to overwrite it? Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Edit: I want to display 4 products instead of 5 products.

Answer (score 0):

to get the results you are looking for you need to change some CSS in your styles.css file:

```
.Content .ProductList li {
    margin: 0 0 20px 75px !important; /* modified! */
}
```

this will get you what you want but changing styles like this is NOT recommended cause this little change might give you headaches in the future :)

Comment: Hi Hossein, thank you for your reply :). 

I should have been a little more clarifying, I just want to display 4 products, rather than the 5. The CSS you gave just brings the 5th one down to a new line :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only first 4 product then please add below css code.

```
.Content .ProductList li:nth-of-type(1n+4) { 
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhoomi, thanks for the reply! :)

I was able to modify the code a bit and got it working with 

'.Content .ProductList li:nth-child(5n) { 
     display:none !important;
}'

this should suffice for now, until I figure out a script that can overwrite it.

Comment: '.Content .ProductList li:nth-child(5n) { display:none !important; }'  this apply to only 5th element if you have more 5 products in future then you have to code like `.Content .ProductList li:nth-of-type(1n+4)` this will display only 4 element. Rest products are not visible to user.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a div right under Mobile_Banner class, it has an inline style:

```
  margin: auto;
    width: 84%;
    text-align: center; <--Add this;
```

Now go to his children, to control their look look for a file called this-is-a-test at line 370:

```
.sml_cat_cont_fifth, .sml_cat_cont_fourth, .sml_cat_cont_second, .sml_cat_cont_third, .sml_cat_cont_first {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
```

Next on the same file, at the next line 371 change the css for .itemzoom:

```
.itemzoom {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now go to cd-styles.css file and change it to:

```
.itemzoom {
    position: relative;
    margin: 2%; <--remove this
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsvxR.jpg

### PS:

By the time I was writing this I think you changed your original question, I thought you wanted all 5. Now to display 4, you can add to any of those divs (.sml_cat_cont_first, second etc) `display:none` and the rest will be automatically centered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will use this as well as I'm going to make the sml_cat_cont_first, second, etc responsive down the line. This should be helpful. What I'm wondering now is why isn't the max-width 100% working by making the squares/blocks smaller when minimizing the window?

Comment: max-width will make the div expand to full length of its parent. In your case there is div in a div. And the outermost divs have a fixed width of 200px as you can see. Try giving them a percentage.